# Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined when using FB.getLoginStatus

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

I'm trying to check if a user has logged in using facebook and get that error in JS console. My code looks like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '######', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
            // request, and the time the access token
            // and signed request each expire
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook,
            // but has not authenticated your app
        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }
    });
</script>
```

What could be the problem and are there any sugestions on how to fix it?

Comment: You are calling `FB.getLoginStatus` before the SDK is loaded and/or initialized. To wait for that, that’s what the `fbAsyncInit` event is for. So put the method call in there.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You are calling FB.getLoginStatus before the SDK is loaded and/or initialized. To wait for that, that’s what the fbAsyncInit event is for. So put the method call in there.

Comment: great advice. I just move the sdk loading script to the top of my javascript page.

Comment: sorry  i dont get you.. i am getting same error what should i do?

Comment: @user1735921: You need to make sure that you don’t call any FB methods before the SDK is initialized. So for methods that you want to call “automatically” (without user interaction, such as a click), you should put them into the `window.fbAsyncInit` function, after the `FB.init` call.

Comment: @CBroe no, I want the user interaction to happen, I have a function named login which has FB.getLoginStatus inside that function, because I need it, and it gives me this error, even though I have FB.init defined in the code like in this question with the correct app id.

Comment: @user1735921 Then you are probably calling that function to early or something. Might be best if you created your own question and show your full code.

Comment: can you add a snip of the correction that you've made please?

Answer (score 55):

In Chrome, you'd be getting the error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined*.

I like to trigger a custom event in Facebook's initialization function, *fbAsyncInit()*.
Then I'm not limited to doing all my FB related scripting inside of the fbAsyncInit function. I can put it anywhere, by just listening for that custom event to be fired.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '123456789',
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true  
    });

    $(document).trigger('fbload');  //  <---- THIS RIGHT HERE TRIGGERS A CUSTOM EVENT CALLED 'fbload'
};

//MEANWHILE IN $(document).ready()
$(document).on(
    'fbload',  //  <---- HERE'S OUR CUSTOM EVENT BEING LISTENED FOR
    function(){
        //some code that requires the FB object
        //such as...
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(res){
            if( res.status == "connected" ){
                FB.api('/me', function(fbUser) {
                    console.log("Open the pod bay doors, " + fbUser.name + ".");
                });
            }
        });

    }
);
```

Answer (score 10):

I used the following simple approach and it works correctly:

In the `head` section I load the SDK:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

Then in the `body` of your page where your actual content is, I used this:

```
<script>

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback2(response);
      }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});

    } else {
      alert("not connected, not logged into facebook, we don't know");
    }
  }

  function statusChangeCallback2(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback2');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      console.log('still not authorized!');

    } else {
      alert("not connected, not logged into facebook, we don't know");
    }
  }

  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1119999988888898981989819891',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
    checkLoginState();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply using script with facbook sdk directly in  tag

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID" id="facebook-jssdk"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

We were facing the same issue, and since FB sdk was not loading (or loading with delays) this was causing problems (or breaking javascript)in some cases which were dependent upon that.

To resolve this issue, we delegated all the calls related to facebook.
We created a function like :

```
function callOnFBSDKLoad(callback){
    if (window.isFBInitialized) {
        callback();
    }
    else {
        jQuery(document).bind('fbInitialized', callback);
    }
}
```

Where `fbInitialized` is a custom event learn more about custom events [here.](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/)
And `window.isFBInitialized` is a variable set when SDK is loaded.

callback is the method enclosing FB related events.
e.g.

```
var FBLogin = function(){
   FB.login(...);
}

callOnFBSDKLoad(FBLogin)
```

PS:
Please ignore syntax and naming conventions, I am basically sharing the idea to resolve such issues.

Comment: Thanks for this easy to implement call queue

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and solid solution. Call a function when the SDK loads. I will name it `triggerLoginCheck()`.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      //TO DO: Add your unique Facebook app ID (All numbers).
      appId      : '***unique_app_id***',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    //Call the function here
    triggerLoginCheck();

    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Later, anywhere, place this:

```
function triggerLoginCheck() {       
       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
       statusChangeCallback(response);
       console.log(response);  
       });
}
```

Comment: Still getting same error as before `Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

It's work fine for me. Is necessary include the Object "Log.info.bind".

```
var Log = { info: { bind: function(){ alert('Hi'); testAPI(); } } }
```